# How to install multiple version pip package

Tags: python, pip

I use package who need some package

```
prompt-toolkit == 0.54
```

another package need

```
prompt-toolkit == 0.46
```

when I upgrade prompt-toolkit to 0.54, another package not work properly

how I deal with it

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot have two versions of the same package in one interpreter/environment.

Comment: so there is no solution about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable with pip, but you could copy different versions of these packages into site-packages/ (say `package_v1` and `package_v2`) and import them as `import package_v1 as package` in your code.

Comment: this will not work since you would have to rename the imports in all libraries that depend on `package` as well.

Comment: yes, this is not going to be easy to deal with other packages if they depend on the one you are trying to use (you could though keep the most recent version's name intact for that reason), but it is true that dependencies management for multiple packages will not be possible.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i can do that, but i need to edit all package who depend on it